# Howto disable filtering of a modal dialog's keypress events

Tags: c#, winforms, imessagefilter

I am running into a strange problem and seem to have to hunted down to the following root cause.
Environment C# (.NET 2.0):

My code is using some vendor's framework and at one time opens a modal dialog. It seems that the framework is filtering on the Application's "Enter" Keypresses (probably by implementing IMessageFilter). As a consequence, closing my dialog by pressing the "OK" button leads to strange behaviour - closing via mouse-click on "OK" works fine. 
Changing the framework's code is unfortunately not an option. So I'd like to disable that the framework notices "Enter" (and probably "ESC") keypresses in my dialog. Does anyone know how this can be done?

**EDIT:**

I "solved" the issue. Please refer the Accepted Answer below.

Comment: What makes you think it is `IMessageFilter`? Your use of "probably" makes me think you need to do more diagnosis before asking for solutions.

Comment: I don't have acces to the framework's source code so I am a bit careful with my claims. I _know_ however that after pressing enter in my dialog, the framework will call another part of my code that is normally called when "enter" is pressed in the UI.

Comment: It's best practice here to post your answer and not edit the question with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "solved" the issue. Here's the solution for future reference: setting the Form's (which was created in the modal dialog) FormBorderStyle property to FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog resolved the issue. Yes, this is a typical case of Cargo-Cult-Programming, but after thorough testing the fix works reliably.

Answer (score -1):

Make a javascript file that keys in on the enter key being pressed, have it execute the ok event on your modal. Just make sure your javascript is above all the other javascript in the applicaiton and it should fire first.

Comment: .NET WinForms applicaton - no Javascript involved